# Distance between two compact sets and a counterexample when these two are only closed

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Here is my exercise that I'm struggling with for 2 days.

Since I'm a beginner for Analysis it is so hard for me to solve.

Please help me...

> Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. For nonempty subsets $A,B\subset X$ define $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b)\vert a\in A~~and~~b\in B\}$. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are compact subspaces then there exist points $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $d(a,b)=d(A,B),$ so in particular $d(A,B)>0$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing.$
>
> Show by an example that both these statements can be false if $A$ and $B$ are only assumed to be closed instead of compact.

Comment: There are sequences $a_n$ in $A,$ $b_n$ in $B,$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) \to d(A,B).$ What do you know about sequences in a compact set?

Comment: If $A,B$ are compact, then $A \times B$ is compact, and so the continuous function $d: A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ must achieve its minimum value. @Rubertos: $A$ is not closed.

Comment: @Shalop You are right. For a counterexample, take $\{n+2^{-n}:n\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @Rubertos: Yes, it is a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are compact, their product $A\times B$ is compact. Hence the function $d:A\times B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has an element $x\in A\times B$ such that $d(x)$ is the infimum. This proves the theorem.

For a counterexample, take $A=\{n+2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}^+$. Note that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ but $\lim 2^{-n}=0$, hence $d(A,B)=0$.

Comment: To be more explicit, the reason that $d$ is continuous is that if $a_n \to a \in A$ and $b_n \to b \in B$, then $$\big|d(a_n,b_n)-d(a,b)\big| \leq \big|d(a_n,b_n)-d(a_n,b) \big|+\big|d(a_n,b)-d(a,b)\big| $$ $$\;\;\;\; \;\leq \big|d(b_n,b)\big|+\big|d(a_n,a)\big| \to 0$$Thus $d(a_n,b_n)\to d(a,b)$, which shows that $d$ is continuous.